# What is the correct way to get the next value in every thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, concurrentdictionary

I have a multi-threaded scenario, I spool up 1000 threads:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<TableNames, int> _lastInsertedIds = new ConcurrentDictionary<TableNames, int>();

Parallel.For(0, 100, i => {
  var id = ++_lastInsertedIds[TableNames.Scores];
});
```

How can I ensure the id is always the next highest no matter what the order of execution?

I would like to avoid using a manual lock object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AddOrUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_AddOrUpdate__0_System_Func__0__1__System_Func__0__1__1__):

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, i => {
  var id = _lastInsertedIds.AddOrUpdate(TableNames.Scores, 1, (key, existing) => existing + 1);
});
```